# How to change distribution name (20.04)

Tags: 20.04

I tried all other guides but none worked. I edited `/etc/lsb-release` to match my OS name, however when I run `lsb_release -a` it still says "Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS" as the description.

Comment: Might need to check `/etc/issue` as well.

Comment: I've edited that file, but it still says "Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS" as the release description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lsb_release` gets the OS name from the file `/usr/lib/os-release`.

If you want modify this file and want your changes to survive upgrades of the package `base-files` you need to run

```
sudo dpkg-divert --add  /usr/lib/os-release
```

first. This will make the package to use the file `/usr/lib/os-release.distrib` instead  and do not touch the file `/usr/lib/os-release`.

Comment: Thanks! This answered my question well.